# Is there a clean way to write a one-line help per choice for argparse choices?

Tags: python, argparse

With python argaparse "`choices`" the default help looks like this:

```
>>> parser.add_argument('move', choices=['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])

positional arguments:
  {rock,paper,scissors}
```

Which works if it's obvious how to pick one, but not so great if each choice needs its own mini-help.

Is there any way to write one line help per choice in a clean way, something along these lines:

```
parser.add_argument("action",
                    choices=[
                        ["status", help="Shows current status of sys"],
                        ["load", help="Load data in DB"],
                        ["dump", help="Dump data to csv"],
                    ],
```

Comment: Don't know about argparse, but I doubt that would be supported. There are other modules for argument processing. I like http://docopt.org/, for example. Rather than building the help message from the arguments you specify, you specify the help message and docopt figures out from it how to parse your command line.

Comment: why not just add `subparsers` if we take `git` for example, you can do,
`git --help` and `git commit --help`. subparser will allow you to do this

Comment: Can't help reccomend http://docopt.org -- it's a billion times better than ArgParse can ever hope to be.

Comment: @Urban48L I hadn't thought of it, but yes this is probably the cleanest solution if you don't want to use other argument parsers such as [clic](http://click.pocoo.org) etc... which is my case here. Thanks.

Comment: I think @Urban48 's comment should be an answer. This is what I ended up implementing.

Answer (score 4):

`argparse` doesn't support this format. Here is my solution. It isn't nice, but it works.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, RawTextHelpFormatter

choices_helper = { "status": "Shows current status of sys",
                   "load": "Load data in DB",
                   "dump": "Dump data to csv"}

parser = ArgumentParser(description='test', formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)    
parser.add_argument("action",
                    choices=choices_helper,
                    help='\n'.join("{}: {}".format(key, value) for key, value in choices_helper.iteritems()))
```

*Try to use [Sub-commands(subparsers)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) is the better idea.*

Comment: `argparse doesn't support this` And that's why ArgParse is lame :) can't even do GNU-style `--help` screens with it :(

Comment: In  your argument definition you can just use `choices=choices_helper`. It will use the dictionary keys as the choices; not need make a list.  I think your approach to pretty-printing a dictionary is great.  It makes a lot of sense to customize the help like this.

Comment: @cat: i confirm your opinion. I have a self modified  `argparse` to do exactly what i want

Answer (score 0):

@julivco's answer produces this help:

```
In [20]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] {load,status,dump}

test

positional arguments:
  {load,status,dump}  load: Load data in DB
                      status: Shows current status of sys
                      dump: Dump data to csv

optional arguments:
  -h, --help          show this help message and exit
```

The `argparse` handling of `choices` is deliberately simple.  It tests with `value in choices`, and iterates through it to construct the `{...}` string.  There are bug/issues looking at improving the string formatting, but no one has asked for/suggested this sort of help formatting.

====================

Here's a custom Action subclass.  It behaves like the usual `store`, but borrows help formatting ideas from the `subparser` Action class. It expects `choices` to be a dictionary (that could easily be changed to a list of lists or tuples).

```
class NewAction(argparse._StoreAction):
    class _ChoicesPseudoAction(argparse.Action):
        # from _SubParsersAction
        def __init__(self, name, aliases, help):
            metavar = dest = name
            if aliases:
                metavar += ' (%s)' % ', '.join(aliases)
            sup = super(NewAction._ChoicesPseudoAction, self)
            sup.__init__(option_strings=[], dest=dest, help=help,
                         metavar=metavar)

    def make_help(self):
        # build list used for help display
        self._choices_actions = []    
        for key in self.choices:        
            help = choice_dict[key]
            choice_action = self._ChoicesPseudoAction(key, [], help)
            self._choices_actions.append(choice_action)

    def _get_subactions(self):
        # called by HelpFormater
        return self._choices_actions

choice_dict = { "status": "Shows current status of sys",
            "load": "Load data in DB",
            "dump": "Dump data to csv"}

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
a = parser.add_argument('--foo', action=NewAction, choices=choice_dict, help='choices help')
a.make_help()

parser.print_help()
print(parser.parse_args('--foo status'.split()))
print(parser.parse_args())
```

output looks like:

```
2028:~/mypy$ python3 stack37094448.py --foo test
usage: stack37094448.py [-h] [--foo {load,dump,status}]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --foo {load,dump,status}
                        choices help
    load                Load data in DB
    dump                Dump data to csv
    status              Shows current status of sys
Namespace(foo='status')
usage: stack37094448.py [-h] [--foo {load,dump,status}]
stack37094448.py: error: argument --foo: invalid choice: 'test' (choose from 'load', 'dump', 'status')
```